# characters special when use read_csv (problem with latin accent)

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying obtain data from different .csv with the next code:

```
lista_archivos <- lapply(documentos, read.csv, head =TRUE, sep= ';', encoding = 'utf-8')
data_bruto <- do.call(rbind , lista_archivos)
```

When I view the table in RStudio, I get the a weird result. I see *A%* when I want to see *DÉBITO AUTOMÁTICO*.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Note that `read.csv` and `read_csv` are different functions. Is your file actually encoded in UTF-8? What happens if you do `encoding="latin1"`?

Comment: You are reason.